# Groovy Byte Array Being Implicitly Cast To ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, groovy, casting

My error:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static test.getLittleEndianSize() is applicable for argument types: (ArrayList) values: [[-128, 0, 0, 0]]

I strictly use byte arrays and never use a def / List anywhere so this is really throwing me off. Any ideas why this happens? As far as I know groovy doesn't redefine primitives like byte[] as implementing List and I haven't been able to find similar errors.

This was originally giving me hell in a larger project and I simplified it down to this code.

```
class test {
    static class Packet {
        byte[] data

        Packet(String data) {
            this.data = data.replaceAll(":", "").decodeHex()
        }

        int size() {
            return data.size()
        }
    }

    static class PacketList {
        List<Packet> packets
        long totalDataSize

        PacketList(String data) {
            packets = new ArrayList<Packet>()
            totalDataSize = 0
            addPacket(data)
        }

        void addPacket(String data) {
            packets += new Packet(data)
            totalDataSize += data.size()
        }

        long getLittleEndianSize() {
            if (packets.size() <= 0)
                return 0

            // Verifying that we're for sure using byte[]
            byte[] firstPacketBytes = packets[0].data
            if (firstPacketBytes?.size() > 0) {

                byte[] lilSizeBytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(firstPacketBytes, 0, 4)
                return getLittleEndianSize(lilSizeBytes)
            }
            return 0
        }

        // No logic in place to decrement size yet
        // No real need for this test
        //
        long getTotalDataSize() {
            return totalDataSize
        }
    }


    static long getLittleEndianSize(byte[] data) {
        if (data?.size() < 4) return -1

        long returnVal = 0
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            returnVal += ((long) data[i] & 0xffL) << (8 * i)
        }

        return returnVal
    }


    static void main(String[] args) {
        String testByteStr = "80:00:00:00:ff:d8:11:12:13:14:15:d9:ff"

        def packets = new PacketList(testByteStr)
        println "${packets.getTotalDataSize()} bytes | Little Endian Header: ${packets.getLittleEndianSize()}"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

groovy 2.4.11

simplified class with problem:

```
public class A{
    public static long fa(byte[]b){
        return b.length;
    }
    static class B{
        byte[] b="123".getBytes();
        long fb(){
            return fa(b); // <<< line 9
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] arg){
        System.out.println ( ">>>" + new B().fb() );
    }
}
```

throws exception:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static A.fa() is applicable 
for argument types: (java.util.ArrayList) values: [[49, 50, 51]]
Possible solutions: fa([B), is(java.lang.Object), wait(), any(), find(), wait(long)
   at A$B.fb(ConsoleScript49:9)
   at A.main(ConsoleScript49:14)
```

seems groovy can't find static method from outer class...

you see (java.util.ArrayList) in error because groovy tries to find different variants of the method and probably  that's the last try.

in java this code successfully compiled.

to fix this in groovy add `@groovy.transform.CompileStatic` annotation on outer class or on inner class, or specify exact method location:

```
        return A.fa(b); // <<< line 9
```